# Show discrete values on legend from layer with Singleband Pseudocolor (PyQGIS 3.22)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, symbology

I'm coding in standalone ambient on VsCode.

My function applies a pseudocolor in a raster. I get a right result, but shows wrong values in the legend of the result layer:

Here's my code:

```
def apply_singleband_pseudocolor(self, layer_name):
    # Carrega a camada
    layer = self.project.mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    # Pega os valores maximos e minimos da banda
    provider = layer.dataProvider()
    ext = provider.extent()
    stats = provider.bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All, ext, 0)
    min = stats.minimumValue
    max = stats.maximumValue
    fcn = QgsColorRampShader()
    fcn.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.Interpolated)
    passo = (max-min)/4
    lst =   [QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(min, QColor(215,25,28)),
            QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(min+passo, QColor(253, 174, 97)),
            QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(min+passo+passo, QColor(255, 255, 192)),
            QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(min+passo+passo+passo, QColor(166, 217, 106)),
            QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(min+passo+passo+passo+passo, QColor(26, 150, 65))]
    fcn.setColorRampItemList(lst)
    shader = QgsRasterShader()
    shader.setRasterShaderFunction(fcn)
    rlayer = self.project.mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(rlayer.dataProvider(), 1, shader)
    rlayer.setRenderer(renderer)
    rlayer.triggerRepaint()
    print(" Camada Banda simples falsa-cor adicionada")
```

[image: Wrong legend values]

When I apply the same symbology by the QGIS GUI, the legend is right:

[image]

I need the correct values on legend to plot on layout. How to fix that problem?

Answer (score 6):

You don't set minimum/maximum values. This is why you get the wrong legend. When using GUI, QGIS does it itself.

```
min_ = stats.minimumValue
max_ = stats.maximumValue

....

renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(layer.dataProvider(), 1, shader)
renderer.setClassificationMax(max_)
renderer.setClassificationMin(min_)
```

I recommend not using `min` and `max` as variable names because they are built-in Python functions.

Without min/max:

[image]

With min/max:

[image]